# Replacing FileInputStream with getResourceAsStream

Tags: java

I am currently reading in a public key file using the following code:

```
    // Read Public Key.
    File filePublicKey = new File(path + "/public.key");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path + "/public.key");
    byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) filePublicKey.length()];
    fis.read(encodedPublicKey);
    fis.close();
```

However, I wish to include the key files in with my jar. I have dragged the key files into my project in eclipse and I am trying to load the public key using the following to replace what is above:

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/RSAAlgorithm2/public.key" );
    byte[] encodedPublicKey = new byte[(int) 2375];
    is.read(encodedPublicKey);
    is.close();
```

However I keep getting a NullPointerException.

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at RSA.LoadKeyPair(RSA.java:122)    at
>   RSA.main(RSA.java:31)

Is this because I am incorrectly loading in the file? Can files be dragged into eclipse and loaded like this or is it a requirement to have them seperate from the JAR?

Comment: If you add a stack trace it is always useful to indicate what line it is referring to. In your case (`RSA.main(RSA.java:31)`) I would expect that `is.read(encodedPublicKey);` is line number 31 in `RSA.java`.

Comment: It depends where you have dragged the public.key file, it must be available on the classpath. This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094786/how-do-i-use-the-java-classloader-to-load-a-file-fromthe-classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `is` is `null` after doing `getResourceAsStream`. If it is, the resource has not been found. In this case check the path to the file, it is relative to your classpath. I don't know your project setup but I would try to simply use `"/public.key"`…

Comment: Thanks, it was null. I didn't realise the files had to be in the src folder.

Answer (score 0):

With this name, you have to put the "public.key" file in the RSAAlgorithm2 package. That means in your "jar" file, you should see an entry named  "RSAAlgorithm2/public.key".