# Java: Can't read a file in my project directory?

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin

I'm building a Vaadin(basically Java that compiles to html/javascript) project and am trying to import a template(basically a HTML file). For all intents and purposes thought, I'm just importing a file as an input stream. Here is the offending code:

```
File file = new File("C:/JavaProjects/VaadinSpikeWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CISTVaadinClient/VAADIN/themes/layoutsinteractionDetailsTabLayout.html");
InputStream is = null;
CustomLayout custom = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    System.out.println("mark 1");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    custom = new CustomLayout(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("mark 2");
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

What I'm doing:

- Deploying the Vaadin project (basically a dynamic web project with a few extra .jars) to tomcat and accessing thVe aadin Project using my browser

What I'm seeing:

- A blank screen in my browser
- File not found exception (i.e "mark 1")
- And as a result: IOException (i.e. "Mark 2")

What I've checked:

- The file definitely does deploy to tomcat with the rest of the project
- Outside of the webapps folder, the file i'm trying to import is available via the browser once deployed (i.e. Localhost/myProject/MyFile.html)
- The Tomcat install is fine (It was a fresh install and works with this/other projects outside of this problem)

What I've tried

- Using a relative URL, or just the name of the file (i.e. New File( "../webapps/vaadin/layouts/MyFile.html") )
- Using the absolute Path to the Project directory
- Using the absolute path to the deploy directory (as above)
- Putting the file somewhere else (read: Every single possible location in the project)

Again, I'm trying to simply read the file, MyFile.html as an input stream. What am I doing wrong/ overlooking?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: drag and drop the file in to a command prompt so you get the path, or rigth click and get properties in windows explorer(i see a c: so its windows?) and then use notepad/ textpad to replace all \ with / or escape \\

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to make it more portable: have you thought about bringing your templates into your `classpath`?  Something like

```
yourApp/WEB-INF/classes/templates/layoutsinteractionDetailsTabLayout.html
```

This way, you only need this line of code, assuming you are into a Servlet or Spring Controller or Struts 1/2 action or whatever called `YourClass`:

```
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("templates/layoutsinteractionDetailsTabLayout.html");
```

Comment: That is certainly something I would do, but I'd like to get this very basic 'read the file' approach working before I tried something else.

Comment: In that case, maybe you are reading a directory too volatile or temporary or subject to eclipse mangling.  Have you tried copying your templates to a well-known directory in your machine and trying your code with that route?

Answer (score 0):

I had no problems reading files when using VaadinService which points to WebContent directory (with META-INF, VAADIN and WEB-INF inside). If it's run in the test environment then VaadinService is not available, so I use such piece of code:

```
private static final String BASEDIR;
static {
    if (VaadinService.getCurrent() != null) {
        BASEDIR = VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        BASEDIR = "WebContent";
    }
}
```

then to navigate to VAADIN folder just use

```
BASEDIR+="/VAADIN/restOfYourPath"
```

Answer (score 0):

*If you are really trying to use this file as an HTML template*, you'll be much better off to leverage Vaadin's support for this. They have a [`CustomLayout`](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.customlayout.html) which loads an HTML template from your theme.

Your template would go into a folder like the following:

```
VAADIN/themes/mytheme/layout/layoutsinteractionDetailsTabLayout.html
```

Note that `mytheme` is the name of your theme and `layout` is a specially recognized Vaadin directory within themes.

Your custom component would then look like:

```
public class InteractionDetailsTabLayout extends CustomLayout {

  private static final String TEMPLATE = "layoutsinteractionDetailsTabLayout";

  public InteractionDetailsTabLayout() {
    super(TEMPLATE);
  }

}
```

Note that the super constructor argument excludes the directory and file suffix.

*If you actually want to load a file in your webapp*, don't bother with it in your `VAADIN` directory but instead put it in your classpath resources and access it with the [`ClassLoader`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094786/how-do-i-use-the-java-classloader-to-load-a-file-fromthe-classpath).